# Sound plays through earphones but not through speakers

Tags: sound, soundcard

I have Ubuntu 13.04.

A couple of minutes after system start I only get sound through external devices (headphones, hdmi) but not from the internal speakers.

The sound card works fine in W8. I have installed alsa and pulseaudio.

I tried to fix the problem with alsamixer with no result.

Expected: Sound through speakers when earphones are not connected.

Observed: Start up sound can be heard. After a couple of seconds sound though speakers stops. Sound can be heard through external devices (HDMI, earphones) but not through internal speakers

I have a laptop with Core i3. I am a new user of Ubuntu. What I can add is the following information:

```
juan@juan-A24:~$ uname -r 
3.8.0-30-generic 
juan@juan-A24:~$ lspci | grep Audio 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05) 
juan@juan-A24:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec 
Codec: Conexant CX20585 Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
```

Additional information:

```
juan@juan-A24:~$ sudo lspci -nn
[sudo] password for juan: 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
juan@juan-A24:~$ sudo lshw --class X
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.16
uso: lshw [-formato] [-opciones ...]
       lshw -version

    -versión de programa de muestra (B.02.16)

el formato puede ser
    - salida de estructura de hardware en HTML
    - salida de estructura de hardware en XML
    - salida de rutas cortas de hardware
    -businfo muestra información del bus

las opciones pueden ser
    -class CLASS solo muestra un cierto tipo de hardware
    -C CLASS es igual que «-class CLASS»
    -c CLASS es igual que «-class CLASS»
    -disable TEST desactiva una prueba (tipo pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST activa una prueba (tipo pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet no muestra el estado
    -sanitize sanea la salida (elimina información sensible tipo números de serie, etc.)
    -numeric muestra IDs numéricos (para PCI, USB, etc.)

juan@juan-A24:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 43
juan@juan-A24:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 
Codec: Conexant CX20585
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f15069
Subsystem Id: 0x1b0a2098
Revision Id: 0x100302
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
GPIO: io=4, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[3]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CONEXANT Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70000c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x07, nsteps=0x07, stepsize=0x0f, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00]
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Control: name="Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Internal Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Internal Mic Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Device: name="CONEXANT Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x46 0x46] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17 0x18* 0x23 0x24
Node 0x15 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x16 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x17 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x18 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x04 0x04]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x04211040: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11*
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Control: name="Internal Mic Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00001324: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x90a70120: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00011334: IN OUT EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x04a11030: [Jack] Mic at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x20 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x21 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x22 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x21
Node 0x23 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x24 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11
Node 0x25 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
juan@juan-A24:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: If you need addtional information please tell me how to get it.
Thanks again

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.